# Event Calendar extension current-week view

Tags: civievent, calendar

I want to show one week of events using the Event Calendar extension without having a timescale for the day as the default "Week" view provides. As shown highlighted but always for the current week.
[image: Example]

Is this possible?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the [CiviCalendar extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicalendar) (backend), you find the respective setting under **Administration / Calendar Settings > Default tab for calendar**.

[image]

If your question is about the [Event Calendar Extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/event-calendar-extension) (frontend), you could untick the option "Show Events by Month?" and load the main calendar-`<div>` with `class="fc-view fc-agendaWeek-view fc-agenda-view"` in order to force the week-view.

[image]

I hope, this helps.

Best,
guitarman

Comment: Thanks for your response.
That sounds like it would be a global change and would prevent the Event Calendar extension from being viewed elsewhere in the Month view. Is that true? I am not  an advanced user of these systems.  We would want to be able to show the compressed Week view that I have described on one page without losing the ability to view the full month view on another page.

Comment: A bit more info.  This calendar view https://www.melbpc.org.au/event-calendar/
has been implemented for us by our CiviCRM support provider in a shortcode so I guess I will channel your suggested approach to them.
Thanks for your input.

Comment: It's not true, that the month view can't be loaded afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the additional info.

You could easily do this in jquery as follows:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
  initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
  ...});
```

[Fullcalendar Manual](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialView)